# Clear user input on console before enter is pressed

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application, cin

I'm trying to program a console game, and the player is supposed to be able to open chests. To do this the user needs to press 'E' while facing a chest (not really important to the question, just giving context) and then a menu appears, asking for input with cin.

So, I use GetAsyncKeyState('E') to detect the 'E' key press. Everything goes as planned, it triggers when 'E' is pressed and the "inventory menu" is opened. The problem is that now the user wrote an 'e' (or multiple) to the console already.
I want this not to happen, as the user will have to backspace in order to enter the desired input.

```
if(GetAsyncKeyState('E')){
    int choice;

    cout << "Inventory Menu" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Take item" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Store item" << endl;
    cin >> choice; //there's already an 'e' on the console
}
```

Comment: Look at [`std::cin.ignore()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Comment: I sure did look into it. Just doesn't work as expected, at least not for me, in this situation. If anything, could you tell me exactly how to implement it and how it should work? An 'e' is still shown in the console for me.

Comment: GetAsyncKeyState is not the correct way to read input in a console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem.

The standard library does not allow a way to do this, as its only designed for basic I/O.

But since I'm already using the WinAPI, there's a way to flush the input buffer:
`FlushConsoleInputBuffer(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE));`

Original answer to a similar question: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/159796/