# Clear console input after GetKeyState()

Tags: c++, winapi, input, console-application

I have a console login-system for creating a username after pressing '1'. But whenever i press that key, the pressed key shows up in the console input. I want to get rid of that.

```
#include <Windows.h>

    bool pressed1;
    std::string inputUsername;
    
    do
    {
        pressed1 = GetKeyState('1') & 0x8000;
        if (pressed1) {
            std::cout << "\nPressed '1' enter username: ";
            std::cin >> inputUsername;
        }
    } while (!pressed1);
```

So when executing and pressing '1' the console says:

```
Pressed '1' enter username: 1
```

How do i get rid of the pressed button in the input?

Comment: Calling GetKeyState in a console app is always wrong. Calling GetKeyState in a polling loop is always wrong.

Comment: I'm just giving you a hint so you don't base your design on a flawed input model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FlushConsoleInputBuffer(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE))`

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void main()
{
    bool pressed1;
    std::string inputUsername;

    do
    {
        pressed1 = GetKeyState(VK_F1) & 0x8000;
        if (pressed1) {
            std::cout << "\nPressed 'F1' enter username: ";
            FlushConsoleInputBuffer(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE));
            std::cin >> inputUsername;
        }
    } while (!pressed1);
}
```

See also this previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55504728/clear-user-input-on-console-before-enter-is-pressed).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer unfortunately the solution you suggested only works if the input Key is 'F1'. If i'm using '1' or '2' as in my example the same problem remains... Also i tested it with 'F1' and in that case it seems to not matter at all whether you add the FlushConsoleInputBuffer or not.